# Как сделать падающий снег в AndEngine?

Tags: android, andengine

Здравствуйте! Я пытаюсь сделать падающий снег в `AndEngine`. Вроде бы как существуют модификаторы для движения спрайтов, но я ничего не могу найти.

```
public Scene onLoadScene() {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    pX = randomGenerator.nextInt(CAMERA_WIDTH);
    Sprite snow = new Sprite (pX, 1, 30, 30, mTextureSnowRegion);
    scene.getLastChild().attachChild(snow);
return scene;}
```

По итогу создается одна снежинка с произвольной начальной координатой "х" и с `у=1`.
А вот теперь внимание вопрос:

1. Как заставить эту снежинку падать?
2. Как сделать так, чтобы снежинки появлялись с определенной периодичностью и, достигнув нижнего края камеры, исчезали?

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы объекты на сцене в AndEngine падали, нужна гравитация. Добавить её в ваше приложение можно с помощью расширения Physics Box2D Extension. Подробный пример, как это сделать, есть [в этой статье](http://findevelop.blogspot.com/2011/12/android-andengine-physics-box2d.html).